# Redirecting a Wildcard Subdomain Properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wildcard

Not sure how to do this, I would like to Redirect a **Wildcard SubDomain**  to either the main index or a 404, i have had a lot of sub-domains in the past and i am not using them any more so to eliminate redirecting each one i wanna redirect sub-domains that don't exist

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to get this done